# Scipy Curve_fit: Why is my fitting so poor and how to improve it?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit my data using curve_fit library of python. Although I can capture the pattern of the data the real fit is rather poor. Is there any way I can improve the quality of the fit?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x=np.array([ 4.29977288,  4.18759576,  3.937875  ,  3.68784896,  3.43711213,
    3.19099287,  2.94166468,  2.68543877,  2.4289324 ,  2.19035861,
    1.93962193,  1.69285434,  1.44271633,  1.18869615,  0.94761142,
    0.69828307,  0.44606364,  0.19355101, -0.05367106, -0.30303661,
   -0.55272018, -0.79877747, -1.04806864, -1.29706657, -1.54567223,
   -1.79685098, -2.05011095, -2.29874144, -2.54813208, -2.80178461,
   -3.04828379, -3.29893363, -3.54727073, -3.79908534, -4.04661293]);

y=np.array([ 20.8744534 ,  20.89824536,  20.3763843 ,  19.79924837,
    19.19485964,  18.57716717,  17.93772371,  17.28834168,
    16.62367817,  15.94336213,  15.24389099,  14.52471466,
    13.7787734 ,  13.00299723,  12.18721413,  11.31510566,
    10.36672642,   9.32224105,   8.14237084,   6.78034367,
     5.19700447,   3.32945537,   1.10437136,  -1.48805508,
    -4.25695201,  -6.94906329,  -9.41648974, -11.54747381,
   -13.33444597, -14.90663076, -16.36783375, -17.72241553,
   -18.9592222 , -20.06703821, -21.07669491])

def func(x,A,B,C):
    a=1+B/A
    b=1-B/A
    k=C/np.log(a/b)
    y=A*np.tanh((x-C)/(2*k))
    return y

A_0=25
B_0=10
C_0=1.2


popt,pcov = curve_fit(func,x,y,p0=[A_0,B_0,C_0])
print(pcov)

plt.plot(x,y,label='Data')
plt.plot(x,func(x, *popt),'.',label='Fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

it's not a problem of `curve_fit` but of the function you are using. Finding a function that will do the job is not always easy but an error function, for example, does a lot better:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import special
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x=np.array([ 4.29977288,  4.18759576,  3.937875  ,  3.68784896,  3.43711213,
    3.19099287,  2.94166468,  2.68543877,  2.4289324 ,  2.19035861,
    1.93962193,  1.69285434,  1.44271633,  1.18869615,  0.94761142,
    0.69828307,  0.44606364,  0.19355101, -0.05367106, -0.30303661,
   -0.55272018, -0.79877747, -1.04806864, -1.29706657, -1.54567223,
   -1.79685098, -2.05011095, -2.29874144, -2.54813208, -2.80178461,
   -3.04828379, -3.29893363, -3.54727073, -3.79908534, -4.04661293]);

y=np.array([ 20.8744534 ,  20.89824536,  20.3763843 ,  19.79924837,
    19.19485964,  18.57716717,  17.93772371,  17.28834168,
    16.62367817,  15.94336213,  15.24389099,  14.52471466,
    13.7787734 ,  13.00299723,  12.18721413,  11.31510566,
    10.36672642,   9.32224105,   8.14237084,   6.78034367,
     5.19700447,   3.32945537,   1.10437136,  -1.48805508,
    -4.25695201,  -6.94906329,  -9.41648974, -11.54747381,
   -13.33444597, -14.90663076, -16.36783375, -17.72241553,
   -18.9592222 , -20.06703821, -21.07669491])

def func(x,A,B,C):
    a=1+B/A
    b=1-B/A
    k=C/np.log(a/b)
    y=A*np.tanh((x-C)/(2*k))
    return y

def erf(x, a, b, c, d):
    return d + 0.5*c*(1 + special.erf(a*(x-b)))

A_0=25
B_0=10
C_0=1.2


popt,pcov = curve_fit(func,x,y,p0=[A_0,B_0,C_0])
perf, pecov = curve_fit(erf, x, y, p0=(0.5,0,40,-20))

plt.plot(x,y, 'o', label='Data')
plt.plot(x,func(x, *popt),'-',label='Fit')
plt.plot(x, erf(x, *perf), '--', label='erf fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent work, so I upvoted. Please see my answer to this questions for additional comment on the shape of the data.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you are bound to use such functions as you are using, or you can also live with a polynomial. In the latter case, you can use `polyfit`.

Remember, you can't just use any higher order polynomial or else you will end up overfitting your data. You can look at the root mean square error of the fit, to gauge its accuracy

```
fit = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 5))

plt.plot(x, y, '.', label='Data')
plt.plot(x, fit(x), label='Fit')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Good fit, and I noticed something in your plot that I also found when making an equation search: the left-most point on the plot has the curve rising above the left-most data point. If it is required, giving this point additional weight in the regression can reduce this end-point curvature.

Comment: @JamesPhillips : Yes, you can create a polynomial which is -21 approx. at x=-4.1 so as to enforce the curve starting at the first point instead of rising. I am not exactly sure how but just some idea

Answer (score 0):

I thought perhaps a sigmoid or peak equation might model the data, and here are example plots of a peak equation and the modeling errors:

[image: models] [image: errors]

It is as if there were two combined signals, one of which is a low-amplitude cyclical signal. This second signal is not a simple sine wave. My thinking is that you might need a complex model that is the sum of two different equations to capture both of these two components in a single model.